# Running Lagom Service Locator / Kafka / Cassandra separately

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, service-locator, lagom

In order to have a complete control on the components of my architecture, I'd like to deploy all the infrastructure components (Service Locator, Cassandra, Kafka) and services individually.

I'm able to run a service with a command as follows: `mvn lagom:startServiceLocator lagom:startCassandra -pl hello-impl lagom:run`

However, when I start these components individually (i.e. by `mvn lagom:startServiceLocator`), the started component terminates automatically. In this case, I see the following logs but the locator is not available at `http://localhost:9008`.

I'm on a local development environment with no proxy and using the default configurations.

How can I run those individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java/Maven**:
If you want to run several Lagom microservices, you just need to do what you was doing:

```
mvn lagom:startServiceLocator lagom:startCassandra -pl hello-impl lagom:run
```

It will start locator, cassandra, if you need you can add kafka, after that, you just run in new cmd following command:

```
mvn -pl second-lagom-microservice-impl lagom:run
```

Now it will connect to running in first command cassandra and locator.

Lagom does not allow you to run cassandra or locator without running service.

**Scala/Sbt**:

For sbt the same approach, we need to run first microservice with all needed services:

```
sbt lagomServiceLocatorStart lagomCassandraStart lagomKafkaStart microservice-impl/run
```

Then just run another like:
`**sbt another-microservice-impl/run**`

Also, you can add an alias in ***build.sbt*** for your microservice to run it individually:

```
addCommandAlias(s"runMicrocervice1", ";lagomServiceLocatorStart;lagomCassandraStart;lagomKafkaStart;microservice1-impl/run")
```

And just run it as:

```
sbt runMicrocervice1
```

Comment: Is the behaviour you described specific to the lagom maven plugin or isn't it somehow possible to start locator individually by implementing a script like in the maven plugin? I'm now trying to come up with a launcher as in: https://github.com/lagom/lagom/blob/4cde9400c1e86d1eb6d168c764bb60aae0e3e6d6/dev/maven-plugin/src/main/scala/com/lightbend/lagom/maven/ServerMojos.scala#L163 Do you think it is possible?

Comment: It is Lagom specific, we have the same issue on scala and sbt. Lagom guys said that it not possible to run it separately.